# BinaryFormatterでクラスのシリアライズ時に暗号化とDeflate圧縮をしたい

Tags: c#

お世話になります。
C#のBinaryFormatterでのシリアル化についての質問です。
[前回の質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/61543/c%e3%81%aedeflatestream%e3%81%ab%e3%81%a4%e3%81%84%e3%81%a6)を参考に暗号化したバイナリ配列をDeflate圧縮させることはできたのですが、巨大なクラスをシリアル化しようとすると、OutOfMemoryExceptionが発生してしまいます。
あまりきれいではないかつ長いですが、ソースコードを貼り付けますので、どのあたりを直したらよいか、アドバイスをいただけますと幸いです。

```
//パスワードをあらかじめ指定しておく。
private string encrypt_key = "testpassword";

public save(){
//とりあえず、クラスをバイト型配列に変換しておく。
//今回はtest_dataに対象のデータが入っているものとする。
byte[] bytes;
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()){
BinaryFormatter formatter = new     BinaryFormatter();
formatter.Serialize(ms, test_data);
bytes = ms.ToArray();
}
//できたデータを暗号化する。
bytes = Encrypt(bytes);
//あとはDeflateで圧縮して、ファイルに書き込む。
using (Stream stream = new FileStream("test_data.bin", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)){
using (DeflateStream ds = new DeflateStream(stream, CompressionLevel.Optimal)){
ds.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
}
bytes = null;
}

private byte[] Encrypt(byte[] bytes){
//byte[] bytes;
SymmetricAlgorithm algorithm = new AesManaged();
algorithm.BlockSize = 128;
algorithm.KeySize = 128;                // KeySize = 16bytes
algorithm.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;        // CBC mode
algorithm.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;    // Padding mode is "PKCS7".

//ソルト、キーおよびIVを生成。
Rfc2898DeriveBytes deriveBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(encrypt_key, 16);
byte[] salt = new byte[16];
salt = deriveBytes.Salt;
byte[] key = deriveBytes.GetBytes(16);
algorithm.Key = key;
algorithm.GenerateIV();
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()){
//復号化の際に利用できるよう、先ほど生成したソルトとIVを書き込む。
ms.Write(salt, 0, 16);
ms.Write(algorithm.IV, 0, 16);
//暗号化を行う。
using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, algorithm.CreateEncryptor(algorithm.Key, algorithm.IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write)){
cs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
//MemoryStreamの内容をバイト型配列に変換。
bytes = ms.ToArray();
}
//暗号化結果を返す。
return bytes;
}
```

一応エラー内容も貼り付けておきます。

```
種類 'System.OutOfMemoryException' の例外がスローされました。
   場所 System.IO.MemoryStream.set_Capacity(Int32 value)
   場所 System.IO.MemoryStream.EnsureCapacity(Int32 value)
   場所 System.IO.MemoryStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   場所 System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   場所 Encrypt(Byte[] bytes)
   場所 save()
```

以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 例外が発生したのはどの行でしょうか？ またその際のStackTraceもあると解決につながるかもしれません。それとは別に暗号化したデータは圧縮してもあまり効果は期待できません。

Comment: 補足的な  暗号化の後に圧縮するのではなく、圧縮した後に暗号化すると改善されるかもしれません。

Comment: この辺の記事のどれかが参考になるかも。[Encrypt .NET binary serialization stream](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28791185/9014308), [Serialize, Compress and Encrypt in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34586087/9014308), [HansHinnekint/EncryptionLib](https://github.com/HansHinnekint/EncryptionLib), [gauteh/crypttest.cs](https://gist.github.com/gauteh/669901/9928f254983e816a4ccbc02d0f81e026941affd0), [Easy object serialization to a file with compression and encryption](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?661477-Easy-object-serialization-to-a-file-with-compression-and-encryption)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FileStream`も`DeflateStream`も`CryptoStream`、そして`MemoryStream`もすべて`Stream`で統一されたインターフェース（正確には基本クラス）が用意されています。
`MemoryStream`で一旦バイト配列を経由するのではなく、必要な相手に直接書き込んではどうでしょうか？

```
using (var fs = new FileStream("test_data.bin", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
using (var ds = new DeflateStream(fs, CompressionLevel.Optimal))
using (var deriveBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(encrypt_key, 16))
using (var aes = Aes.Create()) {
    aes.BlockSize = 128;
    aes.KeySize = 128;
    aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
    aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
    aes.Key = deriveBytes.GetBytes(16);
    aes.GenerateIV();
    ds.Write(deriveBytes.Salt, 0, 16);
    ds.Write(aes.IV, 0, 16);
    using (var encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor())
    using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ds, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        cs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
```

Comment: うまくいきました。ようやくストリームについて、少し理解できた気がします。ありがとうございました。